# querying mysql rows with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, excel

hi friends my problem is i have some excel sheets which are uploaded to database then that data will be retrieved and posted in a web portal.

my problem is i cant able to query particular data which is marked in this pic

can anyone help me query only numbers[all] without '%' and assign them to a variable .....

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if(!$con)die (msql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db("csv");

if(!$db) die(mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("select * from users");

$rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
______________________________________________________
**if i have column like this how to extract only 1,12,14,60,4 ? without '%'
and also remove first row "High value %" and post them in this format
$output = array(1,12,14,60,4)**
______________________________________________________
High value%
1%
12%
14%
60%
4%
```

Comment: If you're starting out with `mysql_query` you're already digging yourself a hole. That interface is deprecated and is being removed from PHP in the near future. At the very least use [PDO](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059). Even better would be a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that provides a lot of examples for solving this sort of problem.

Comment: Near future? From everything I've read, they're talking about 5 years or better. I'm not sure the sky is falling or that this user is digging a hole just yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `trim` function, to get rid of the '%' characters.

I code the following test:

```
$test = "15%";
echo trim($test,"%");
```

`----------FULL TEST--------------`

```
$test = "15%"; //test case
echo "Test:".trim($test,"%")."</br>";

$rows = array('1%','2%','3%');
$aux = array();

foreach($rows as $key)
{
echo trim($key,"%")."</br>"; //just output
$aux[] = trim($key,"%"); //or transforming
}

var_dump($aux);
```

Mysql version:

```
set @test = "15%";
select trim(BOTH '%' FROM @test);

#Retrieve all rows but first
select name,trim(BOTH '%' FROM lastname) as normal,trim(BOTH '%' FROM email) as high 
from users limit 1,1000;


#select row based on Normal %
select name, trim(BOTH '%' FROM lastname) as normal,trim(BOTH '%' FROM email) as high
from users
where trim(BOTH '%' FROM lastname) = 5;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf0b2/5

Codepad: http://codepad.viper-7.com/fmw59H (updated)

Comment: but the problem is how to retrieve the data from database in first place??? think my table is like this                                                                   High Value%                                                               40%                                                                  50%                                                                  30%......... will  you write some code for me that would be helpful in a great way.. i just need this data in plain array format so that i can plot them in my web portal

Comment: Did you check the var_dump($aux); ??

Comment: "http://i57.tinypic.com/9gy2r7.jpg"  just check that image and help me write a code the fetch only numbers ......            .......  that test code is working but i dont know how to get my data look like that array('1%','2%','4%') from mysql database

Comment: bro that code is helpful but each time data updated is different so i cant call something like " where trim (Both '%' from last name ) = 5;....is there any dynamic way to do that

Comment: Yes..you can get the value 5 from a form or from a link and do the query on your php script